# AngularJS: A Table Directive with Cell Templates

Tags: angularjs, scope

I am writing an Angular directive that generates a `<table>` element based on the data specified in its `contents` attribute. I would like to allow the user to be able to specify an Angular template for each of the table's cells.

The tricky part is that I would like the cell templates to be compiled *against the scope of the controller outside the template, but augmented with cell-specific content*.

For example, say I have directive for displays flags. The flag images are preloaded by my main page's controller, and the directive simply chooses among them based on its `country` attribute. I give a template and a list of countries to the `tabulate` directive, which should render one flag per country. But how do I define the template such that it uses the `flags` defined in the main page's controller, but the `country` defined in the `tabulate` link function?

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hd8p9/).

Comment: You create a service that provides the flags.

Comment: What If I want different controllers to provide different flags?